# phpMyAdmin access on local environment with Vagrant/easyengine

Tags: phpmyadmin, vagrant

I'm trying to use easyengine with Vagrant to create a local development environment. I have installed the ubuntu/trusty32 box, and installed easyengine, then I created my site, without problems. But now when I try to access the phpMyAdmin (mydomain.com/pma), inserting the wp-config.php credentials, nothing happens. I tried to access with easyengine/easyengine, root, mysql too, and nothing. Same problem occurs acessing via myip:22222

What could be the problem? (Chrome don't recognizes as a https connection, but I choose to continue, maybe this is the problem?)

Answer (score 1):

If you tried the solution from previous answer, then also you can try [this one](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/vagrant/#forwarding-port-80-from-mac) (if you're using Mac OS X as me).

And finally you can try simply to change HTTP authentication credentials for your EasyEngine install by using this command - `ee secure --auth`. More information about it you can find by [this link](https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/docs/commands/ee-secure/).

It works for me. Please note that I also implemented both previous solutions too before I tried the last one.

Hope that it will help someone too, who will google this question as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to forward 22222 from host machine to guest machine.

Please try adding following line in you Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22222, host: 22222
```

You changing Vagrantfile you will may need to run `vagrant reload` command.

Comment: I made the changes you told me, but the problem persists: I try to login, but login popup appears again.

My Vagrantfile: http://pastebin.com/K6b3vGhq